# Get error messages yet continue execution in SMO

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, smo

I'm working on rewriting the app we use to run upgrades on our database. Basically the idea of the app is it takes a bunch of scripts (one for each version) and runs each script between the current version of the database and the most recent version it has. I'm trying to find a better way for us to handle this process and I tried to make SQL Management Objects work the way we need them. For reference, here are the limitations I have to work with.

- It has to handle GO statements (which SMO does)
- It can't require us to modify the files we have. (This will be used with hundreds, maybe thousands of files and we don't want to have to go edit each one of them manually, so adding try catches are kinda out of the question)
- It has to continue to the next GO statement if it encounters an error. This is mostly to match the way our current app works. If an error is encountered in one of the batches of the script we want it to continue on to the next one since they are most of the time unrelated.
- If the script encounters an error, it has to output an error message so the user can know a version's upgrade didn't work, and so the developers can correct the error for the next version (here is the problem)

Here's what I currently have as a code:

```cs
string messages = "";

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string setup = File.ReadAllText(@"[redacted]\Setup.sql");
    string script = File.ReadAllText(@"[redacted]\6.3.6002.0.sql");
    string script2 = File.ReadAllText(@"[redacted]\6.3.6003.0.sql");

    var cnx = new SqlConnection(/*proper connection string*/);

    var server = new Server(new ServerConnection(cnx));
    //server.ConnectionContext.InfoMessage += ConnectionContext_InfoMessage;
    server.ConnectionContext.ServerMessage += ConnectionContext_ServerMessage;

    server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(setup);
    server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
    server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script2, ExecutionTypes.ContinueOnError);

    txtResult.Text = messages;
}

private void ConnectionContext_ServerMessage(object sender, ServerMessageEventArgs e)
{
    messages += e.Error.Message + "\r\n";
}
```

And here are the scripts I'm using:

Setup.sql:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'UPGRADE_HISTORY')
DROP TABLE UPGRADE_HISTORY

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = N'TEST_CODE_TABLE')
    DROP TABLE TEST_CODE_TABLE

CREATE TABLE UPGRADE_HISTORY (
    UPDATE_DATE     DATE            NOT NULL,
    VERSION_TXT     VARCHAR(50)     NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY     (UPDATE_DATE, VERSION_TXT)
)

CREATE TABLE TEST_CODE_TABLE (
    CODE_VALUE      INT             PRIMARY KEY,
    DESCRIPTION_TXT VARCHAR(250)    NOT NULL        
)

INSERT INTO UPGRADE_HISTORY VALUES
(DATEADD(d, -3, GETDATE()), '6.2.5000'),
(DATEADD(d, -1, GETDATE()), '6.2.5001'),
(DATEADD(d, -1, GETDATE()), '6.2.5002'),
(DATEADD(d, -1, GETDATE()), '6.3.6000.0'),
(DATEADD(d, -1, GETDATE()), '6.3.6001.0')

INSERT INTO TEST_CODE_TABLE VALUES
(1001, 'Test Code Table'),
(1002, 'Test Code Table 2')
```

6.3.6602.0.sql:

```
INSERT INTO UPGRADE_HISTORY VALUES
(GETDATE(), '6.3.6001.0')

GO

PRINT 'Test Code Table Change'
GO

UPDATE TEST_CODE_TABLE SET DESCRIPTION_TXT = 'Test Code Table Change' WHERE CODE_VALUE = 1002;
GO
```

6.3.6003.0.sql:

```
INSERT INTO UPGRADE_HISTORY VALUES
(GETDATE(), '6.3.6003.0')

GO

PRINT 'Test Error'
GO

INSERT INTO CODE_TABLE VALUES (1001, 'Test') 

--This will throw an error since this will conflict with the primary key
--of the code table (or you know, because I just noticed it doesn't call
--the right table, it's really relevant since I want it to throw an  
--error, w/e what it is)

GO

PRINT 'Second Test Code Table Change'
GO

UPDATE TEST_CODE_TABLE SET DESCRIPTION_TXT = 'Test Code Table Change 2' WHERE CODE_VALUE = 1002;

--We still want this to execute.    

GO
```

This is to reproduce a situation that can happen in our updates. So, as it is, the setup is only to create recreate the database each time so I can use the same scripts, then the first upgrade file is to simulate a functioning as intended file, then finally the 2nd upgrade file is to simulate an upgrade file that has an error. And this is where the problems start. As I've got it working at the moment, when the second script is executed, the first part runs, then the second part runs and errors out, but I don't get an error message. Neither the `InfoMessage` nor the `ServerMessage` events get fired. Then the third part runs (the one after the statement that errors out), and I get a ServerMessage for the print. For reference, here's the output I'm receiving:

```
Test Code Table Change
Test Error
Second Test Code Table Change
```

The print before and after the errors happen, and I can confirm from double checking the data that the `UPDATE` statement after the error is also executed. However, no message or error is thrown for the fact that the `INSERT` statement throws an error. We would really need to have SMO throw an error, or trigger the `ServerMessage` event, or anything really. Is there something I'm missing, or is this a shortcoming of the framework.